# How can I get the regular price in the invoice pdf in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, price, invoice, pdf

I used

```
getPrice()
```

but I want the regular price after adding customize variable and the price of that.
As shown in image below.
[image]

Comment: Did you try $orderItem->getBasePriceInclTax(); ?

Comment: @Klettseb yes I tried, not giving regular price.

Comment: hm get price should normally give you this price and not the discounted one

Comment: How can I get Regular price as shown in image.